# Задача RMQ Fast

Tags: c++

Реализуйте структуру данных, которая на данном массиве из
N
целых чисел позволяет узнать максимальное значение на этом массиве и индекс элемента, на котором достигается это максимальное значение.
Формат ввода
В первой строке вводится натуральное число
N
(
1
≤
N
≤
1
0
5
) – количество элементов в массиве. В следующей строке содержатся
N
целых чисел, не превосходящих по модулю 10̂9 – элементы массива. Далее идет число
K
(
0
≤
K
≤
1
0
5
) – количество запросов к структуре данных. Каждая из следующих
K
строк содержит два целых числа
l
и
r
(
1
≤
l
≤
r
≤
N
) – левую и правую границы отрезка в массиве для данного запроса.
Формат вывода
Для каждого из запросов выведите два числа: наибольшее значение среди элементов массива на отрезке от
l
до
r
и индекс одного из элементов массива, принадлежащий отрезку от
l
до
r
, на котором достигается этот максимум.

Ограничение по времени 0.3 сек, по памяти 512мб
Вот мой код:
constexpr int kmax=17,nmax=100000;
pii sparse[kmax][nmax];

```
pii get_max(int l,int r,vector<int>& deg){
    int k=deg[r-l+1];
    pii ans=mp(0,0);

ans.first=max(sparse[k][l].first,sparse[k][r-(1<<k)+1].first);
ans.second=(sparse[k][l].first>sparse[k][r-(1<<k)+1].first?sparse[k][l].second:sparse[k][r-(1<<k)+1].second);

return ans;
}

int main() {

int n,m,l,r;
cin>>n;

vector<int> a(n+1),deg(n+1);
for(int i=1;i<=n;++i)
    cin>>a[i];

cin>>m;

for(int i=1;i<=n;++i){
    sparse[0][i].first=a[i];
    sparse[0][i].second=i;

}

for(int k=0;k<kmax-1;++k)
for(int i=1;i<=n;++i){
    int j=min(i+(1<<k),n);
    sparse[k+1][i].first=max(sparse[k][i].first,sparse[k][j].first);
    sparse[k+1][i].second=(sparse[k+1][i].first==sparse[k][i].first?sparse[k][i].second:sparse[k][j].second);
}

deg[1]=0;
for(int a=2;a<=n;++a){
    deg[a]=deg[a-1];
    if(!(a&(a-1)))
        ++deg[a];
}

for(int i=0;i<m;++i){
    cin>>l>>r;
    pii tmp=get_max(l,r,deg);
    cout<<tmp.first<<' '<<tmp.second<<endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

Ловлю TL 348 ms. Как можно решить эту задачу? Я уже не знаю, как ускорить решение, разве есть что - то быстрее разреженной таблицы?

Comment: Это не ваше задача? https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2578245.html

Comment: Перепишите на ДО, асимптотика изменится с nlogn+k -> n+klogn, на и храните в ячейке ДО сразу индекс элемента, в теории будет работать чуть быстрее